# How Do I Get Dual Monitors To Work in Slackware 14 using XFCE?

Tags: linux, kde, slackware, xfce

Just installed Slackware 14 and using KDE both monitors work great. I can stretch the desktop across both monitors. However, if I startx using XFCE I can't seem to figure out how to configure the dual monitor setup. By default both monitors are mirrored. I need help figuring out how to configure a dual monitor setup with XFCE so that the desktop is stretched across both screens just like KDE.

Answer (score 1):

xrandr is always a mighty alternative if your window manager does not offer the right options for multiple monitors.

Check the output of "xrandr" to see the available monitors and resolutions.

Check "xrandr --help", especially for the option --right-of.